# query with verified if table exist

Tags: mysql

I have table v_c_country with column table_name

I can make an query and, as result, have the list of all tables from column table_names. Generally, it means. I have it as source to another query. 
But what in situation when the list of table_names are different than list of original exists tables f.ex. from  information_schema.tables? (f.ex. we prepare info about tables witch will be create in the future).

How to make a query on table v_c_country with result a list of table_names but verified with f.ex. information_schema.tables? (list only with names of real existing tables)
Example pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select c.table_name from v_c_country c
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES i on i.TABLE_NAME = c.table_name
```

Comment: thank you, but it don't work for me, err -> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. I try it few times ...

Comment: @Andrew: That's odd. It works for me. See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/495bf/1). What is your exact query?

Comment: And your error looks more like a PHP error message than a sql error.

Comment: ok, I did make it very very simple query and this don't want to work. $STH_1 = $DBH_R->query("

select c.table_name from v_c_country c 
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES i on i.TABLE_NAME = c.table_name 
      
       ");
      
while (($row_1 = $STH_1 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null){

echo $row_1['table_name'];
echo "<br>";

}

Comment: @Andrew: I am not so fit in PHP but shouldn't `fetch_assoc()) !== null)`be `fetch_assoc()) != null)`? There is a `=` too much in it.

Comment: you are right but it's not a problem. As I see in your example - it is working. As you see in a simple query - not. Can it be a problem with a dbase version, my is 5.1 and your is 5.5.2?

Comment: @Andrew: You could output the error message. See here [fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121027/). I don't think it is the DB version. This table is available in MySQL 5.1

Comment: The error info -> Unknown column 'c.table_name' in 'field list'

Comment: my mistake, i'm working with two dbases, local and in net - wrong connection, sorry :((( All is working ok, thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two equivalent ways to do this:

```
select *
from v_c_country c join
     information_schema.tables t
     on c.table_name = t.table_name
```

or

```
select *
from v_c_country c
where c.table_name in (select table_name from information_schema.tables t)
```

Comment: thnks for your help, none of above work, the err is -> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. I try it few times ...

Comment: sorry - of course all is working ok, my mistake, sorry and thank you for help

Comment: No problem.  You make yourself more popular if you accept answers and vote up responses.

Comment: ech, I'm not looking for any popularity, I'm looking here for a real help from peple who have knowledge, as you, f.ex. But, of course, it's nice to receive a vote as a thanks for your help. Than I try to vote up responses, but very often comments do not contribute entries to correct the problem. Sometimes I think that people write without an idea for a solution to the problem. But sometimes the negative hints help think through the problem differently.